# how to submit a simple form after choosing radio button option

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a simple HTML form with 2 radio button options and I would like to call different webpages for each radio button chosen

I've been trying with javascript but I'm new with javascript, is there a way of doing it by using jquery?

Here is my HTML :

```
<form action="" id="formoid" title="" method="post">
 <div><input type="radio" name="op" id="op" value="student"><span>student</span>
 <input type="radio" name="op" id="op" value="company"><span>company</span>  
 </div>
 </div>
 <div><input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit"></div>
</form>
```

thanks!

Comment: When you say 'call different webpages' do you mean you want the page to go to a particular page, or load the content of that page into the current page?

Comment: You've demonstrated none of the JS you've tried.

Comment: @DavidThomas what the page go to a particular page like:
if user chooses option 'student' and submit goes to page X
chooses option 'company' and submit goes to page Y

Answer (score 0, accepted):

javascript

```
<form action="#a" name="f1" title="" method="post" onSubmit=doSubmit()>
    <div><input type="radio" name="op" id="op" value="student"><span>student</span>
    <input type="radio" name="op" id="op" value="company">    <span>company</span>                        </div>
    </div>
    <div><input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit"></div>

    </form>

    <script>

function getRadioButtonValue(rbutton)
      {
        for (var i = 0; i < rbutton.length; ++i)
        {
          if (rbutton[i].checked)
            return rbutton[i].value;
        }
        return null;
      }


    function doSubmit(){
        val = getRadioButtonValue( document.f1.op)  

        if(val == "student"){
                document.f1.action = "student.html"
            }else{
            document.f1.action = "company.html"
        }
        document.f1.submit()
    }

    </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if i got you right, but if you mean changing aciton attribute of form then use following:

```
<form action="" id="formoid" title="" method="post">
    <div><input type="radio" name="op" id="op" value="student" data-action="http://foo-bar.baz/form.php"><span>student</span>
    <input type="radio" name="op" id="op" value="company" data-action="http://foo-bar2.baz/form.asp"><span>company</span>                        </div>
    </div>
    <div><input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit"></div>
</form>
```

and add javascript code after that (having jQuery loaded):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#formoid radio[name="op"]').click( function() {
        $('#formoid').attr('action', $(this).attr('data-action') );
    } );
</script>
```

btw. you have invalid html structure, it's good idea to fix it as well :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#submit").click(function(){
var val = $("input[type='radio']:checked").val();

if(val == "student"){
//post to 1 page
}

if(val == "company"){
//post to 1 page
}
```